# Determine CaseSensitive in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

for example TableColumn could be contains value in forms `New`, `new` or `NEW`, how can I write query that returns only

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn = 'New'
```

but doesn't returns TableRows contains `new` or `NEW`

Comment: You have tagged mysql, sql, sql-server-2008 as well as oracle. Which database are you using?

Comment: @Eljakim that isn't jocke, all of tagged

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want a single query that will perform a case-sensitive comparison and will work across all of these database platforms? Or did you just tag extra platforms to get more eyeballs on your question?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, huuuuh, but btw no problem, on VMware are installed these three SQL Engine's types as I tagged, I programatically going across those instances and to test Native OS (Win & Solaris) and get infos from Metadata, queries, traffic counter, nothing complicated, another question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For MySQL, a simple option is:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn = 'New'
AND BINARY(myColumn) = BINARY('New');
```

The second condition is logically sufficient, but makes the query slow if the table is big (the Index on `myColumn` cannot be used). The combination of the 2 conditions allows index use for the first condition, and then filtering out the non matching case.

Comment: simple and quickly thanks +1, but works only if I delete `myColumn = 'New'` in MySQL engine

Comment: Index problem can be solved without hacks too. We only need to change the collation of a column to binary one.

Comment: @mKorbel - if it doesn't work you may have a syntax issue. It should work (tested) on MySQL with InnoDb.

Comment: @Karolis - would changing the column collation affect all select statements? Or would it allow using the index with BINARY() or COLLATE when explicitly requested?

Comment: @Galz Yes. Changing the collation affects all select statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use COLLATE in your where clause

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn COLLATE latin1_general_cs = 'New'
```

Comment: agreed with @Karolis looks like as not works for innoDB engine

Comment: @mKorbel: I think this will work with InooDB (works for me), but the collation you need to use depends on your DB settings. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-collation-charset.html.

Comment: @mKorbel This method works with innodb tables. Innodb is just one of engines which is supported by MySQL.

Comment: @Galz to MySQL, I tried that with replace `latin1_general_cs` to `uft8` or `uft8_genereal_ci` .... (`SELECT COLLATION(USER()), COLLATION('@');` returns `uft8_genereal_ci`), without success

Comment: mKorbel CI at the end means Case-Insensitive. You want CS at the end for Case-Sensitive.

Comment: @mKorbel If you need utf8, then you can use **uft8_bin** collation.

Comment: @Karolis (@Raj More)forgot for that, without success, both `MySQL` instances (5.1.47 and fresh  installed 5.5.9) doesn't allows me to set `Collation` with `Case Sensitive` for `UFT8 Charset`, just all of `Collations` ends with `_ci`, no idea for community versions (home PC), for sn'Oracle and MsSQL works both, but BINARY looks like as faster for SQL interpreter

Comment: @mKorbel MySQL supports binary collations. What do you mean by saying that all of the collations ends with **_ci**? Set the collation manually and set it for the column not for table.

Comment: @Karolis all available collations for uft8 are CaseInsensitive, no idea why, for latin1 is there latin1_general_ci and latin1_general_cs, and works correctly for example here posted, just question are we sure that we're going right direction, if uft8 supported in MySQL CaseInsensitive and CaseSensitive COLLATION too

Comment: @mKorbel I don't understand. What error do you get when you try to set **uft8_bin** collation?

Comment: @Karolis `Unknow collation: uft8_bin (1237)`, but as I mentioned only for `uft8`, for another collations works (table contains only `ASCII charset`), but joke is that `BINARY()` (by @Galz) looks like as  faster that explicit `COLLATE something`

Comment: @mKorbel not uft8_bin but utf8_bin :)

Comment: @mKorbel If you want a really fast solution, you have to specify the collation explicitly for the column of the table. And then you will not need to specify the collation in SELECT statement :) Of course you should have an index on that column.

Comment: @ Karolis my stupid mistake, thanks, that really cross-platform, cross collations ...,

Answer (score 1):

The Best Way to make this column case sensitive is change this particular column if charset is UTF8 change it's collation to collate utf8_bin, after the modification of column it search case sensitive.

i.e I have a table name people with column name "name".

```
     alter table people 
     modify column name varchar(50) charset utf8 collate utf8_bin;
```

Note : You can   use varchar data type to varbinary, it works fine..

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE BINARY userid = 'Rahul';
mysql does not check case of word so in the case of username or userid we shouold need to check case also for more security.
I hope this will help you